# Installing binary crt in nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, ssl-certificate

I installed some certificates in apache with no worries, but now I've been given a binary crt file to install it in nginx. I am more fond of apache so I tried there before. There is no way I can load it using SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile.

I was guessing the file was wrong and I needed the ascii files I am used to. But the customer is positive the file is right and they are using it. They sent me a bunch of pem , chain and other files and I tried countless combinations of them with no luck in apache nor in nginx.

I've been googling about it but I can't find documentation about binary certificates, the searches bring me to other kind of cert problems. I guess I am not asking the right question. Can someone please address me to some documentation about installing this kind of certs ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"binary" is not a file format. You need to find out what format it is, then, if necessary convert the certificate and key file to PEM (the file you have been supplied with may contain both).

You didn't say what OS you are using. On Linux/Unix

```
file your.crt
```

should tell you what the current file format is and the openssl command will convert the file. You mention 'crt' in the subject which is commonly used for DER encoded certificates...hence...

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in your.crt -out your.pem
```

But do make sure you keep the key seperate.